# How to add pagination to FirebaseAnimatedList

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'd like to paginate with `FirebaseAnimatedList` but I don't know how to do it. 
I set `ScrollController` to controller property and was able to get notified when scroll to top but I don't know how to fetch additional data after that.

Does anyone know how to paginate?

Code:

```
int limit = 15;

 @override
  void initState() {
    this.roomId = widget.roomId;
    listScrollController = new ScrollController()..addListener(_listener);
    super.initState();
  }
     _listener() {
        if (listScrollController.position.pixels ==
                listScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
          // fetch additional here
        }
      } 
    new Flexible(
            child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
              controller: listScrollController,
              query: FirebaseDatabase.instance
                  .reference()
                  .child('chat')
                  .child(roomId)
                  .limitToLast(limit),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: true,
              sort: (a, b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key),
              //comparing timestamp of messages to check which one would appear first
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot messageSnapshot,
                  Animation<double> animation, int index) {
                return new ChatMessageListItem(
                  messageSnapshot: messageSnapshot,
                  animation: animation,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, `FirebaseAnimatedList` does not support pagination yet. You need to write your own pagination login for that and user `AnimatedList` to display children.

Comment: Thank you I’ll take different approach then!